# How to say thank you to colleagues for gifts

Tags: company-culture

I became a father recently, and it's sort of company culture to collect money and get gifts for the father/mother on their baby's birth or any other life event.

I am not sure what could I put in "Thank You" Email to all employees. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple 1-2 lines Thank You e-mail would do. The e-mail can go somewhat like this:

> Dear colleagues,
>
> Thank you for making my special day even better. I am humbled by all your wishes and the gifts.
>
> Thank you for showering your blessings on my little one. Means a lot.
>
> regards,
>
> XYZ

Comment: i received gifts after 1 weeks holiday, so i am not sure putting "Thank you for making my special day even better" would be appropriate, but rest is excellent, thank you ---- maybe i can change it to  "Thank you for making these special days even better" ?

Comment: Maybe you can substitute _day_ with **occasion** and use the line.